# Encryption using Javascript without sacrificing performance

Tags: javascript, performance, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I would like to enhance my web application by including symmetric encryption techniques using Javascript but I fear that I will lose the performance. Can you suggest me some good approaches please?

Comment: Encryption is needed or it isn't. Use as appropriate. Worry about performance when/if it is an issue. Keep in mind that Javascript is susceptible to inspection (or exploits/injection) and SSL already does a fair job at what it was designed to do. Perhaps provide more information in the question?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good start

http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Answer (score 0):

Encryption requires CPU time. You **will** sacrifice performance. You need to determine how much is too much and profile.

Why aren't you using HTTPS ?